# How to query base class in JPA with JOINED strategy

Tags: jpa, inheritance, orm, openjpa

I have a class hierarchy mapped to a database using the JOINED strategy.  I set discriminator values on the subclasses.  When I persist an entity, the propery joined tables are populated and my discriminator column contains the correct discriminator for the class persisted to that row.

When I try to read back the data by either querying the base entity or through a relation on the base entity, I get the error:

```
<openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Could not map discriminator value "LabEngagement" to any known subclasses of the requested class "com.cerner.chronicle.fable.models.stories.Story" (known discriminator values: [Story]).
```

The list of known discriminator values does not contain the discriminator values I set on my subclasses.

My Entities are defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STORY")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Story extends AuditedEntity {}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_STORY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "UserStory")
public class UserStory extends Story {}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_STORY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ServiceAccount")
public class ServiceAccountStory extends Story {}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAB_ENGAGEMENT_STORY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "LabEngagement")
public class LabEngagementStory extends Story {}
```

I expect to be able to be able to run a query against the base entity with code such as:

```
final CriteriaQuery<Story> criteriaQuery = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Story.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(criteriaQuery.from(Story.class));

final TypedQuery<Story> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

final List<Story> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

and have the discriminator value be used to instantiate the proper Story type so that my results would contain both UserStory and ServiceAccountStory stories.  Instead, I get the error noted above.

I can query the subclasses successfully by querying against the subclass entity:

```
final CriteriaQuery<UserStory> criteriaQuery = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(UserStory.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(criteriaQuery.from(UserStory.class));

final TypedQuery<UserStory> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

final List<UserStory> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

but then I only get the list of UserStories.

It's unclear what value setting a discriminator provides if it doesn't allow for work against the base class.  If I need to specify the subclass I clearly already know the type I'm dealing with and do not need a discriminator.

Am I doing something wrong?  Are my expectations wrong?

Comment: The error clearly references a value "LabEngagement". Where is that coming from? My guess is you have a record in one of the tables with that value for the discrimintaor column.

Comment: Sorry, for simplicity, I left that and a few other sub classes out of the initial question.  LabEngagementStory is a subclass of Story same as UserStory and ServiceAccountStory.  I will update the question to include it but I get the same error with UserStory or ServiceAccountStory.  The root problem seems to be that the discriminator sub classes aren't known when JPA tries to read in a Story.

Comment: You don't *need* a Discriminator column/value for JOINED inheritance (only for single table). That said, I wouldn't expect its presence to break. http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_joined You can try removing. See also:http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_discrim.html

Comment: What JPA provider are you using. It works fine for me with Hibernate. I get `[model.UserStory@7555b920, model.ServiceAccountStory@4152d38d]`

Comment: Also, I get a validation error: `No discriminator column should be defined for non-root entity "Story"`

Comment: Agreed that a discriminator for JOINED strategy is not necessarily required...but my understanding is that that is provider dependent and I was having similar issues without one.  I'll have to go back and retry...maybe I know more now and can get it to work.  We're, unfortunately, stuck with OpenJPA 2.4.2 for this project at the moment.  A couple of months from now we should be up to the latest Hibernate version, but for now we have some tech stack issues we don't have time to migrate off :(

Comment: I'm starting to suspect an OpenJPA bug.  If the first thing I do with an EntityManager is a write, the discriminator appears to work as expected.  That is I can write then read back the inheritance entity.  If the first action on a fresh EntityManager is a read , I get discriminator errors.  It's looking like maybe OpenJPA isn't tracking on the inheritance until after a write has been performed?

Comment: I tried the same code minus discriminators at all.  Same behavior.  If I write first, then I can read back.  If I try to read first I get "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate abstract class of type "com.cerner.chronicle.fable.models.stories.Story"... this may indicate that the inheritance discriminator for the class is not configured correctly".